# React Native Duplicate module name

Tags: android, react-native

Our webapp depends on React 15. To maintain parity between the Android/iOS devices, `import React from "react";` should yield React 15 even on the devices. However, after installing react@15.0.2 via npm and attempting to start the Android app in dev mode, I'm a receiving this error:

> Failed to build DependencyGraph: @providesModule naming collision:
>   Duplicate module name: IOSDefaultEventPluginOrder   Paths:
>   /node_modules/react/lib/IOSDefaultEventPluginOrder.js collides
>   with
>   /node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ReactIOS/IOSDefaultEventPluginOrder.js
>
> This error is caused by a @providesModule declaration with the same
>   name accross two different files. Error: @providesModule naming
>   collision:   Duplicate module name: IOSDefaultEventPluginOrder
>   Paths: /node_modules/react/lib/IOSDefaultEventPluginOrder.js
>   collides with
>   /node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ReactIOS/IOSDefaultEventPluginOrder.js
>
> This error is caused by a @providesModule declaration with the same
>   name accross two different files.
>       at HasteMap._updateHasteMap (/node_modules/node-haste/lib/DependencyGraph/HasteMap.js:160:15)
>       at /node_modules/node-haste/lib/DependencyGraph/HasteMap.js:125:25

I understand that this is due to React and React Native containing the same js file, but does anyone know if there is a way to properly resolve these dependencies?

Environment:
- Mac OSX (latest)
- Android (have not tested on iOS)
- React Native 0.25.0-rc

Comment: Solution was posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43540811/duplicate-module-name-react-native-vector-icons?answertab=active#tab-top) I posted the solution at there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never mind - updating to React Native 26.0-rc fixes this issue since React 15.0.2 is now a dependency.

Comment: `26.0-rc` has some other problems too. :(