# Duplicate module name: react-native-vector-icons

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux, native-base

When I install NativeBase and React-Native-Router-Flux in my react-native project I get this error:

```
Failed to build DependencyGraph: @providesModule naming collision:
  Duplicate module name: react-native-vector-icons
  Paths: /Users/vittori/Desktop/repos/GitHubExamples/native-starter-kit/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/core/__fixtures__/files/package.json collides with /Users/vittori/Desktop/repos/GitHubExamples/native-starter-kit/node_modules/react-native-router-flux/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/core/__fixtures__/files/package.json

This error is caused by a @providesModule declaration with the same name across two different files.
Error: @providesModule naming collision:
  Duplicate module name: react-native-vector-icons
  Paths: /Users/vittori/Desktop/repos/GitHubExamples/native-starter-kit/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/core/__fixtures__/files/package.json collides with /Users/vittori/Desktop/repos/GitHubExamples/native-starter-kit/node_modules/react-native-router-flux/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/core/__fixtures__/files/package.json

This error is caused by a @providesModule declaration with the same name across two different files.
    at HasteMap._updateHasteMap (/Users/vittori/Desktop/repos/GitHubExamples/native-starter-kit/node_modules/react-native/packager/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/HasteMap.js:159:13)
    at p.getName.then.name (/Users/vittori/Desktop/repos/GitHubExamples/native-starter-kit/node_modules/react-native/packager/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/HasteMap.js:134:31)
```

Comment: I'm having the same exact problem arise when starting with `react-native start`. Running `npm i` does have some warnings for react-dom, react-native, react-native-maps, react-native and react-static-container requiring a peer of react. I've tried many things such as cleaning the npm cache, deleting node_modules, upgrading using react-native. Let me know how you get on :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution was posted [here](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/1803)

`yarn add react-native-router-flux@3.38.0`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to update 
[react-native-router-flux](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux) using: 
`npm i react-native-router-flux --save`

It may be that trying to start the react-native packager fails again and running may be useful:

`` 1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
 2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
 3. Reset packager cache: `rm -fr $TMPDIR/react-*` or `npm start --reset-cache`. ``

You may see once attempting to run the packager again errors such as:

`Failed to build DependencyGraph: @providesModule naming collision:
Duplicate module name`

You may need to run the npm install for react-native-router-flux again.

Comment: Tried these instructions 3 times with a fresh codebase.  Also tried clearing everything out and using `yarn.`  Same errors occur

Answer (score 0):

If you work with yarn, please run this command.
`yarn add react-native-router-flux@3.38.0`

And if you work with npm, please run this command.
`npm install react-native-router-flux@3.38.0 --save`

Also you still get the issue, please downgrade react-native version to 0.41.2.

Then, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

NativeBase [2.1.4](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/releases/tag/v2.1.4) solves this issue